# Populate TreeView from Linq - adds only the last parent item

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, treeview

I'm Loading a TreeView from database with Linq, and my code only add the last parent item but all the category item under that parent item.

My stored prcedures from Linq works fine, i use them else where.

Can someone help me find my error here?

Thanks

```
LinqtoDBDataContext db = new LinqtoDBDataContext();
var parents = db.GetParentCategories();

TreeNode parentNode = null;
foreach (var parent in parents)
{
    parentNode = new TreeNode(parent.ParentCatName.ToString());
    var categories = db.GetCategories(parent.ParentCatID);
    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(category.CategoryName.ToString());
        parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
        var products = db.GetProductsInCategory(category.CategoryID);
        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            TreeNode child3Node = new TreeNode(product.ProductName.ToString());
            childNode.ChildNodes.Add(child3Node);
       }
    }
}
TreeViewProducts.Nodes.Add(parentNode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting your parentNode for every parent. Move `TreeViewProducts.Nodes.Add(parentNode);` into your `foreach` loop.